# Updating file permissions in Capistrano results in 'Argument list too long'

Tags: bash, capistrano

One of the final stages of our deployment script requires all PHP files to be mode `600` to satisfy our `suphp` requirements. In the deploy script we have:

```
run "find /srv/www/xyz/ -type f -name \"*.php\" -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 600"
```

However when we deploy we receive the following error:

```
  * executing "find /srv/www/xyz/ -type f -name \"*.php\" -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 600"
    servers: ["www.xyz.net"]
    [www.xyz.net] executing command
*** [err :: www.xyz.net] sudo
*** [err :: www.xyz.net] :
*** [err :: www.xyz.net] unable to execute /bin/chmod: Argument list too long
*** [err :: www.xyz.net]
    command finished in 333ms
failed: "sh -c 'find /srv/www/xyz/ -type f -name \"*.php\" -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 600'" on www.xyz.net
```

If we run the command manually on the server it works fine. Does anyone possibly understand why we are getting this error when run with Capistrano?

Answer (score 1):

Your command is this:

```
run "find /srv/www/xyz/ -type f -name \"*.php\" -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 600"
```

Not too sure if the `sudo` would work when being piped like this in Capistrano.

Capistrano is great, but none of what it does is magic. Capistrano is essentially a Ruby script that opens up an SSH connection & then runs a pile of shell script commands. So a new SSH connection initiated via Capistrano would be considered a new login to the server. Which means that `sudo` would require a password & Capistrano just doesn’t work that way… Unless you have setup passwordless `sudo` on the server. More details in [the Capistrano documentation](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/authentication-and-authorisation/#toc_8):

> The second part of this topic is that our deploy user needs to be
>   authorised to work in the deployment directory, on the server. That
>   means we need to be able to work, ideally without sudo (none of the
>   default Capistrano recipes expect sudo to be available), **or for your
>   custom recipes, you will need to have configured passwordless sudo.**

Also, it doesn’t seem like you need to escape the double quotes when you use `-name \"*.php\"`, so perhaps just changing ito be like this would work: `-name '*.php'`. Using single quotes since you seem to have been escaping the double quotes to fit the context of the `run` command. I bet those escaped double quotes (`\"`) placed in the context of `run` was the root of this issue:

```
run "find /srv/www/xyz/ -type f -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sudo chmod 600"
```

But past all of that, I would recommend trying this instead:

```
run "find /srv/www/xyz -type f -iwholename '*.php*' -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 600"
```

Note there is no `sudo` in place since if the user was able to create files without `sudo` to begin with, then there is no reason that same user would need to use `sudo` afterwards to change file permission. Also I am using `iwholename` rather than `name`.

I also recommend you use `--no-run-if-empty` if your remote host can handle that `xargs` option:

```
run "find /srv/www/xyz -type f -iwholename '*.php*' -print0 | xargs --no-run-if-empty -0 chmod 600"
```

`--no-run-if-empty` is a GNU extension so it doesn’t work for non-GNU/BSD version of `xargs` used in Mac OS X and such but works well in modern Linux installs (Ubuntu/Debian, CentOS/RedHat).